# Build Cross-Chain DAPPs between EVM and Cosmos non-EVM chains

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, cosmos, axelar

I'm wondering is it possible to build an entire DAPP for example a DEX or NFT marketplace with Axelar that exists on an EVM chain like Avalanche and a Cosmos chain that is non-evm compatible? I am confused how this might work due to the different virtual machines.

I am assuming you cannot just call `callContractWithToken()` on a gateway contract when trying to implement this.

Thanks

I was reading on `sendToken()` and `callContractWithToken()` which is how I have sent tokens between evm chains I know axelar connects cosmos chains as well and am unclear how to send tokens between the chains with different virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible.

Let's assume a scenario where you are sending `ETH` to smart contract A running on Ethereum network (so EVM compatible). Once that's done, you need to a trigger some action on a smart contract B running on Cosmos.

1. Someone sends ETH by calling `sendToken()` of contract A
2. A emits an event called `ETHReceived`. In solidity, this shall look like:

```
event ETHReceived(arguments);

sendToken() public payable {
  ...

  emit ETHReceived(arguments);
}
```

3. You have some server code that's listening to events from A.
   If you are using [ether.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/), it shall look something like:

```
contract.on('ETHReceived', (...arguments) => {
 // trigger an action on Cosmos chain.
});
```

In the callback, you can trigger some action on B's function (non-EVM compatible).

So using events, you just communicated between an EVM and non-EVM compatible smart contracts!

---

Events are the core idea on which Chainlink is built. Refer: https://blog.chain.link/events-and-logging-in-solidity/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to build an entire dApp such as a DEX or NFT marketplace with Axelar that exists on both an EVM chain like Avalanche and a Cosmos chain that is non-EVM compatible.

Axelar delivers secure cross-chain communication for Web3, enabling you to build Interchain dApps that grow beyond a single chain. This means you can build a complete experience for your users that lets them interact with any asset, any application, on any chain [with one click](https://docs.axelar.dev/).

Axelar supports two main types of interchain capabilities: sending tokens and general message passing. The latter allows you to call smart contract functions across blockchains, which can be used to compose DeFi functions, move NFTs cross-chain, or perform cross-chain calls of any kind that sync state securely between dApps on various ecosystems [source](https://docs.axelar.dev/dev/intro).

For EVM chains like Avalanche, validators play a crucial role in supporting and securing the chain. They participate by voting on EVM chain events in a proof-of-stake consensus model. When processing cross-chain messages from a source EVM chain, Axelar validators must query their RPC endpoints from their EVM chain to verify the submitted message [source](https://docs.axelar.dev/learn/validators).

For Cosmos chains, all are automatically supported by default [source](https://docs.axelar.dev/validator/external-chains/overview).

In terms of communication, Axelar uses Gateways. On each chain connected to Axelar network, a Gateway is deployed. On EVM chains, it is a smart contract address. On Cosmos and other non-EVM chains, it is an application with logic and the ability to communicate with Axelar network [source](https://docs.axelar.dev/learn/network/flow).

On each chain connected to Axelar network, a Gateway is deployed. On EVM chains, it is a smart contract address. On Cosmos and other non-EVM chains, it is an application with logic and the ability to communicate with Axelar network. This Gateway is used to receive messages from a connected dApp and send them into the Axelar network for routing to any connected chain.